# Apache CXF as a Jar in Ant project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ant, cxf

Is there any way to use Apache CXF as a JAR for an Ant project? All the examples I have found/tried require you to download Apache CXF to your server and set the installation path as CXF_HOME.
Is it possible to use CXF just by adding CXF JAR to the project instead of installing it on Server?